# Phase portraits with Maxima

Tags: maxima-software

Good morning all,

Just a very quick question:

I am using maxima to try and plot a phase portrait of a System of Differential Equations but im not getting the expected results.

```
u: (x^2-4)(y+2);

v: (x-1)(y^2-9);

sol: solve([u,v],[x,y]);

eqL: makelist(subst(S,point_at(x,y)),S,sol);

sadL: makelist(subst(S,saddle_at(x,y)),S,sol);

snL: makelist(soln_at(pt[1],pt[2]),pt,[[1,1],[-1,1],[1,-1],[-1,-1],[1,2],[1,-2],[3,2],[3,-2]]);

wxdrawdf([u,v],[x,-4,4],[y,-4,4],eqL,sadL,snL)$
```

I must admit ive been working a night shift so I may have missed something obvious but for the life of me I cant seem to spot the problem.

Comment: I don't know these functions. But if you actually wrote `u: (x^2-4)(y+2)` instead of `u: (x^2-4)*(y+2);` this was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

After changing

```
u: (x^2-4)(y+2);
v: (x-1)(y^2-9);
```

to

```
u: (x^2-4)*(y+2);
v: (x-1)*(y^2-9);
```

I get the following picture

[image]